# How to find out the server on which Rails integration test runs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing, minitest

I have the following integration test written up against my working rails app and it passes. However, I have following questions related to this integration test:

1. Why does puts `request.original_url` prints `http://www.example.com` ? Shouldn't it print `localhost:3000` because that's the default port on which the application runs?
2. Does this integration test automatically fires up the server on some port? If yes, then how can I find it out the host name and port ?
3. How can I make the test point to some other server, `www.abcd.com` for example, and see it fail because such host does not even exist?

The integration test are ran using following command:

```
rake test:integration TEST=test/integration/login_test.rb
```

Please guide.

```
require 'integration_test_helper'

class LoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  setup do
    @user = users(:admin)
  end

  test "login page is displayed on root path" do
    delete '/signout'
    get root_path
    puts root_path
    puts request.original_url
    assert redirect?
    assert_redirected_to '/signin'
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template :new
    assert_template %r{\Adevise/sessions/new\Z}
    assert_select "a[href=?]", users_path, count: 0
    assert_select "input[id=?]", 'login-email', count: 1
    assert_select "input[id=?]", 'login-password', count: 1
    assert_select "button[id=?]", 'login', count: 1
  end

end
```

Comment: Answer of Question 1: 

 The original_url method Returns the original requested URL as a
 String.Why it should print localhost:3000 For further details see
 http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Request/original_url

About Question 2: 
You can run integration test without running localhost or without any server, it means integration test did not automatically fires up the server on some port